# Outputting a warning message tag as a string, from a function running inside of a table

Tags: warning-messages

I want to print the messages or warning message tags for `NonlinearModelFit` when batch fitting data. For example, I will import and fit my data with something like

```
Table[
       MyData = Import[DataSetList[[i]]];
           MyFit = NonlinearModelFit[MyData, MyFitFunction[a, b, c, x], {a, b, c}, x];
               MyFitMessageTags = (* ??? *);

       {i, MyFit, MyFitMessageTags},
       {i, 1, NumberOfDatasets}
     ]
```

The idea being that I can easily filter out fit results which have a message or specific message tag. I'm really struggling to find what I want. I've tried `Messages[NonlinearModelFit]` as I read this should output the messages associated to `NonlinearModelFit` from the previous session, but I don't see any change in the messages at all -- possibly because it is inside a table so that only counts as one session?I've also tried `EvaluationData`, but again I don't get what I expect here either.

`Check` could be an option but it seems that if you get any message then you don't get the output from the function. This is undesirable as sometimes Mathematica will issue a warning, even though the output is good. For example if the function has decided a better method should be used and switches from the default.

This should be very easy, and it probably is but I'm looking in the wrong place, but so far I am struggling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one very roundabout way could be to encapsulate the fit in a `Check` and check for a `null`:

```
   MyFitCheck = 
   Check[
          NonlinearModelFit[MyData, MyFitFunction[a, b, c, x], {a, b, c}, x];,
          "FIT WARNING"
        ];   
   FitWarningTag = If[MyFitCheck == Null, "GOOD FIT -- NO WARNING", "FIT WARNING"];
```

It works, but it would be better to output the specific tag.